# ListView Not Showing Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a ListView nested in a  in a simple WPF app. I have the horizontal scrolling property enabled on the ListView, but it never activates so items continue to be truncated horizontally. Hoping someone can point out any obvious errors. XAML:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SoftwareUpdates}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="55" Height="Auto" Margin="9,197,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="570" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=DetailsCheckBox,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="568" Header="Missing Updates:" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `Width` of the column to `Auto` (or equivalently, deleting the `Width` style, assuming there is no default style) gives the required result.

The key is that the data that you don't want to truncate is inside the column, which is truncated in the above code at `Width` 568... But this `Width` actually needs to be able to stretch indefinitely with the data so that it can be scrolled by the scroll bar on the `ListView`.